# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't create my table

```
create table Classroom (
    Classroom_ID varchar2(4000) not null constraint classroom_pk primary key,
    Capacity number not null,
    Number number not null,
    Location varchar2(4000) not null
);
/

alter table Classroom add constraint classroom_classroom_id_uq unique (Classroom_ID);
```

Comment: You've been given the immediate answer, but let me suggest a long-term solution, and that is to give some _serious_ thought to establishing standard naming conventions.  My convention is that all columns are named in the format, 'adjective_noun'.  That will 1) absolutely avoid all reserved words, and 2) make all names more 'self-documenting'.  Consider not only your column 'NUMBER' but 'capacity' and 'location'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUMBER` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ZZPRE/appb.htm#ZZPRE957) in Oracle and you cannot use it as an identifier (unless you use a quoted identifier and use `"NUMBER"`; but don't do that as it is confusing).

Pick another word that means the same thing and use that as the identifier instead. I.e. if number is the number of the classroom then use `room_number`; if it is the number of rooms in that location then use `amount`; or something else similar.

```sql
create table Classroom (
    Classroom_ID varchar2(4000) not null constraint classroom_pk primary key,
    Capacity number not null,
    room_number number not null,
    Location varchar2(4000) not null
);
/
```

Answer (score 1):

`NUMBER` is an Oracle reserved word, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. Chose another column name (or *always* delimit it as `"Number"`.)